# Can we launch google map with designated language by intent ？

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I launch google map by intent and designated language not the same of system default?

Answer (score 1):

Seems no way to set language for Google Maps via Intent: in [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) no information about language, only:

```
geo:latitude,longitude
geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
geo:0,0?q=business+near+city
```

Comment: OK, thank you! So I think just can to change the default language of system to do this.